How to write tests for state changes in React that affect other components in the UI?
UPDATE: I added a waitFor() for my expect(input.value) and was able to get rid of the act error. However, my test is still failing.
I want to test once a valid wallet address is typed into the WalletAddressInput component, the ReqTokensButton will become enabled...
I have the following components:
FaucetCard.js
export default function FaucetCard({ setSuccess, setError }) {
  const [walletAddress, setWalletAddress] = useState("");
  const [showTransactionCard, setShowTransactionCard] = useState(false);
  const [walletBalance, setWalletBalance] = useState(null);
  const [txHash, setTxHash] = useState(null);

  async function callContract() {
    if (!walletAddress) {
      setError("Please enter a valid wallet address!");
      return;
    }

    try {
      setSuccess(
        "Requesting tokens... It may take a few seconds to mine on the testnet."
      );
      const api = new Axios();
      const res = await api.requestTokens(walletAddress);
      setSuccess(res.message);
      setWalletBalance(res.balance);
      setTxHash(res.txHash);
      setShowTransactionCard(true);
    } catch (error) {
      setSuccess("");
      const message = error?.response?.data?.error
        ? JSON.stringify(error.response.data.error)
        : error.message;
      const msg = message ? message : "Check console for error";
      setError(`Something went wrong! Error: ${msg}`);
      console.log(error);
      setShowTransactionCard(false);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="card" data-testid="faucet-card">
      <div className="card-header">
        <h1>Faucet</h1>
        <img src={drip} alt="drippy" />
      </div>
      <div className="button">
        <WalletAddressInput
          type="text"
          variant="outlined"
          placeholder="Address..."
          label="Wallet Address"
          value={walletAddress}
          onChange={(e) => setWalletAddress(e.target.value)}
        />
        <ReqTokensButton
          onClick={callContract}
          isDisabled={!isAddress(walletAddress)}
        />
      </div>
      {showTransactionCard && (
        <div className="transaction-card">
          <TransactionCard
            title={"Transaction success! "}
            txHash={txHash}
            balance={walletBalance}
          />
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

isAddress is a function imported from the ethers.js library that returns a boolean base on if the address provided is valid.
WalletAddressInput.js
const WalletAddressInput = styled(TextField)({
  width: "100%",
  marginBottom: "1em",
  "& .MuiOutlinedInput-root": {
    "& fieldset": {
      borderColor: "#148FA0",
      borderRadius: ".25em",
    },
    "&:hover fieldset": {
      borderColor: "#117684",
    },
    "&.Mui-focused fieldset": {
      borderColor: "#148FA0",
    },
  },
  "& .MuiInputBase-input": {
    fontFamily: "Rubik",
    fontWeight: "400",
    fontSize: "16px",
    color: "#333",
  },
  "& .MuiFormLabel-root": {
    fontFamily: "Rubik",
    fontWeight: "400",
    fontSize: "16px",
    color: "#148FA0",
    "&.Mui-focused": {
      color: "#117684",
    },
  },
});

export default WalletAddressInput;

ReqTokensButton.js
const CustomButton = styled(Button)({
  borderRadius: ".25em",
  width: "252px",
  height: "56px",
  margin: "0 0 0 20px",
  padding: "0",
  "& .MuiTouchRipple-root": {
    color: "#fff",
  },
  boxShadow: "0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25)",
  background: "#148FA0",
  "&:hover": {
    background: "#117684",
    cursor: "pointer",
  },
  border: "none",
  fontFamily: "Rubik",
  fontWeight: "400",
  fontSize: "16px",
  lineHeight: "19px",
  textAlign: "center",
  color: "#FFFFFF",

  // Add styles for the disabled state
  "&:disabled": {
    background: "#B0B0B0",  // Grey background when disabled
    color: "#FFFFFF",        // Keep text white or adjust as needed
    boxShadow: "none",       // Remove shadow to make it look flat
    cursor: "not-allowed",   // Change cursor to not-allowed to indicate it's disabled
  },
});

export default function ReqTokensButton({ onClick, isDisabled }) {
  return (
    <CustomButton data-testid="request-tokens-button" onClick={onClick} disabled={isDisabled}>
      Request Tokens
    </CustomButton>
  );
}

Here is my test:
    jest.mock("ethers/lib/utils.js", () => ({
      isAddress: jest.fn(),
    }));
    
    const validWalletAddress = "0x117875b555f.......";
    
    describe("Request Tokens", () => {
      beforeEach(() => {
        // Reset mocks before each test
        isAddress.mockReset();
      });
    
    it.only("enables the request tokens button if the wallet address input has a valid address", async () => {
        render(<FaucetCard setSuccess={jest.fn()} setError={jest.fn()} />)
    
        const input = screen.getByRole("textbox");
        expect(input).toBeInTheDocument();
        const button = screen.getByTestId("request-tokens-button");
        expect(button).toBeInTheDocument();
    
        // // Simulate user entering a valid wallet address
        userEvent.type(input, validWalletAddress);


        expect(input.value).toBe("0x117875b555f.........");
        await waitFor(() => {
          expect(input.value).toBe("0x117875b555f........");
        });
    
        expect(button).not.toBeDisabled();
      });
    });

My test is failing AND I am getting the following error:

When testing, code that causes React state updates should be wrapped
into act(...):
act(() => {
  /* fire events that update state */
});
/* assert on the output */

This ensures that you're testing the behavior the user would see in the browser. Learn more at

https://reactjs.org/link/wrap-tests-with-act

Not sure if this is the main reason my test is failing or if this is an additional issue. My UI works as intended when I run through it myself.

This seemed to have solved my problem, although I am still getting the act error.
it("enables the request tokens button if the wallet address input has a valid address", async () => {
    isAddress.mockReturnValue(true);

    render(<FaucetCard setSuccess={jest.fn()} setError={jest.fn()} />);

    const input = screen.getByRole("textbox");
    expect(input).toBeInTheDocument();
    const button = screen.getByTestId("request-tokens-button");
    expect(button).toBeInTheDocument();

    userEvent.type(input, validWalletAddress);

    await waitFor(() => {
      expect(isAddress).toHaveBeenCalledWith(validWalletAddress);
    });

    await waitFor(() => {
      expect(input.value).toBe(validWalletAddress);
    });

    await waitFor(() => {
      expect(button).not.toBeDisabled();
    });
  });

